# Accidental revert with svn

Tags: eclipse, svn

yesterday little time before to go out, I made a revert on a few files not commited yet. Now I try to explain my situation.

Yesterday I worked on a few new files inside a package, before to go out, I try to committed this new files together with other things. Absently, I updated the package (without realize that there was a confict ). When i realized of the conflict instead to make commit i made revert and the i lost everythings (also the new file never committed)

Is there a way to retrieve these files?

I'm using eclipse kepler on a windows system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has a local history of files. Right-click on a file, choose "Team - Show Local History", and try to find your previous code there.

See http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm

Answer (score 0):

For already versioned files do as JBNizet said, find your version, right click on it an hit `Get content`.

For unversioned files, if you have already performed a `svn add` i.e. schedule for commit (icon overlay is a `+` sign) - which eclipse automatically does before a commit which you apparently tried, since you have got a conflict - a revert would just remove them from schedule to commit and they are still there (icon overlay turns back from a `+` to a `?` question mark)

Hope you didn't revert twice!